# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level - I'm getting this error despite the indents being done correctly?

Tags: python

```
conloop = False
while conloop == False:
            if solocontinue == "Y" or solocontinue == "y" or solocontinue == "Yes" or solocontinue == "yes":
        os.system("clear")
        sololoop += 1
        conloop = True
        elif solocontinue == "N" or solocontinue == "n" or solocontinue == "No" or solocontinue == "no":
            if len(solos) <= 1: 
                       solos.remove(soloplayer)
               print()
                   print("You do not have atleast 2 contestants!")
               time.sleep(1)
               os.system('clear')
               sololoop += 1
               conloop = True
                elif len(solos) >= 2:
               print()
               print("Returning to menu...")
              time.sleep(1)
              os.system('clear')
              conloop = True
              menu()
```

For some reason, despite the indentations being done correctly, Python tells me that line 10 (in this snippet) is indented incorrectly. Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

Comment: You have indented the while loop in 2nd line, may ask why?

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin It's not actually indented, that's just the code snippet, I'll try to change it now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have mixed tabs and spaces, but they're not directly visible in the question because Stack Overflow renders tabs as 4 spaces. I've closed your question under an existing one that covers this issue as well as a bunch of related tips. BTW, check out [ask] for tips about asking on SO, like starting with your own research and making a [mre].

Comment: *despite the indents being done correctly*: If the interpreter says they are wrong, *they are wrong*. On this subject the interpreter is always right, because it is an operational definition of correctness.